# Como gerar gráfico de linhas e pontos no R com plotly

Tags: r, gráfico, plotly

Estou tentando gerar um gráfico 3D com as coordenadas de 5 pontos.
Estou usando o plotly.

```
library(plotly)

total <- read.csv(mgr-x1.csv, header = TRUE)


fig1 <- plot_ly(total, x = total[,1], y = total[,2], z = total[,3],color = ~Evento, colors = c('#BF382A', '#0C4B8E'),size =12,mode='lines')
fig1 <- fig1 %>% add_markers()
fig1 <- fig1 %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'Easting (m)'),
                                   yaxis = list(title = 'Northing (m)'),
                                   zaxis = list(title = 'Height')))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de conectar os pontos. Alguém sabe como eu faço isso?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Não sei como fazer isso, ou mesmo se é possível fazê-lo, mas uma dica: Gráficos 3D já são de difícil visualização, não tente complicá-los.

Answer (score -1):

Use a opção `mode = "lines+markers"`. Como não postou seus dados mas sua dúvida não depende deles, vou usar um exemplo mínimo genérico:

```
library(plotly)

dados <- iris[c(48:53,148:150),]

plot_ly(dados,
  x = ~Petal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, z = ~Sepal.Length,
  color = ~Species,
  type = "scatter3d", mode = "lines+markers")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]